# add objects to NSMutableArray when defined in .h

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am testing NSMutableArray and do not understand what i am doing wrong.

When i define "myArray" locally the [myArray addObject:@"First line"]; works but if i define it in the .h file it ends up as null.

I am using myArray to add the text of multiple selected cell's in a UITableView "didSelectRowAtIndexPath".

Could someone nice explain what i am doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is in your code - you'll need to paste in the declaration and initialization snippits for someone to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just declaring an NSMutableArray in the header file? If so, it still needs to be initialized somewhere in the .m file. You could do this like so:

```
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:@"First line"];
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. BTW, i guess I should then release it when i leave the UITableView xib?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have it like this in your .h file:

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController {

    NSMutableArray *myArray;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myArray;

@end
```

And in your .m file

```
@implementation YourViewController


@synthesize myArray

//make sure you release it
- (void)dealloc {
    [myArray release];
}

/*....other code..... */

/*make sure it's initialised somewhere */
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myArray = [[NSMutableArray] alloc] init];
}   
@end
```

Comment: Thanks gef, this is exactly how i did it :-)

Answer (score 0):

In .h file

`NSMutableArray *myArray;`

In .m file

`-(void)viewDidLoad

{

[super viewDidLoad];

myArray = [[NSMutableArray] alloc] init];

[myArray addObject:@"myObject"];

}`